# How can I disable caching in Twitter Finagle?

Tags: java, twitter, netty, finagle

It seems like the Twitter Finagle library uses caching when multiple calls are made to the same endpoint.  Normally this would be fine, but it is bad for automated testing.  Is there a cache, can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

Finagle does no such caching...